# Limit address field postcode and city

Tags: commerce, ajax, entities

I need to limit the commerce_customer_address field to 10 cities. You should be able to choose a city from a select list and this should then set the correct postcode. It also needs to be ajaxified so that the postcode updates dynamically. Possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commerce_customer_address is an [Address field](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield). You can add your behavior by implementing a custom format plugin, like the one in the [addressfield_example](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/addressfield/tree/example/plugins/format/address-ch-example.inc) submodule.

Comment: Thanks! That addressfield_example was exactly what I needed.